# Is MUI DataGridPro key a secret?

Tags: material-ui

import { LicenseInfo } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';

LicenseInfo.setLicenseKey(
'x0jTPl0USVkVZV0SsMjM1kDNyADM5cjM2ETPZJVSQhVRsIDN0YTM6IVREJ1T0b9586ef25c9853decfa7709eee27a1e',
);

Should the key be a secret?

Answer (score 0):

No, the license key does not need to be a secret. The only thing asked is not to proactively share your key to others.

http://mui.com/components/data-grid/getting-started/#security